# Bootstrap table not working correctly on Chrome but works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made a table that's inside a modal using Twitter Bootstrap 3. The weird thing is that it works fine on Firefox and jsFiddle but not on Google Chrome.

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#competitor_modal">
    Competitor
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="competitor_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Competitors</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>URL</th>
                                            <th>Final Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>Comp Link</td>
                                            <td>http://www.complink.com.ph/product_info.php?cPath=49_9&amp;products_id=7371</td>
                                            <td>2790.00</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>Gigahertz</td>
                                            <td>http://www.gigahertz.com.ph/products/accessories/headset/a4tech-hs-105</td>
                                            <td>8695.00</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>SM Cyber Zone</td>
                                            <td>http://www.smcyberzone.com/products/mobile-phones/acer/acer-liquid-s1</td>
                                            <td>9800.00</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dsf496jw/3/

Here are some screen shots.

Chrome:
[image: chrome screenshot]

Firefox:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this class to your `<table>`

```
.my-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsf496jw/4/)

It works in `md` and `lg` screens though it's not perfect for mobile.

Comment: Sure, you could also add inline widths to the `<td>` tags like `<td style="width:20%">` to adjust the column widths (total between four columns should equal 100%).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Chrome is not a fan of scrolling tables, and bootstrap likes to render the table 
to fit all the data regardless. In Firefox it scrolls, in chrome it doesn't.

One solution is to wrap the table in a scrollable div.
Maybe trigger on  a smaller screen small screensize to fix Christain's answer?

Answer (score 2):

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9349fe34/

[image]

It would be more user friendly, IMO, to make the width auto. It sizes down nicely and the responsive table will kick in at the 767px break point (default).

Add class `.table-modal` to the modal

```
<div class="modal fade table-modal" id="competitor_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Add CSS:

```
.table-modal .modal-dialog {width:auto;max-width:1000px;}
.table-modal {padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;} /* put this in a 768px min-width */
```

And remove the .row and col-*-12 and the .container-fluid inside the modal-body, it's not necessary. The padding on the modal-body will work great.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was experiencing this problem with Bootstrap 4 in Chrome (v. 79.0.3945.79 on Ubuntu 18.04).

The slide bar does not appear, or -more exactly- it just shows briefly as I resize down and then vanishes. However, the bar remains visible/drag-able on firefox as I expected.

The **"solution"** is just that **Chrome** **does not show** the scroll bar, and **the scrollbar functionality is  rendered in as the table itself**.  In other words, you use your finger/mouse to **drag the table itself** left/right just as you would the scrollbar.

I'm 5 years late to this party, but hopefully this message will save someone some time in 2020 and beyond.